# How to call load function with React useEffect only once and without loop

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem useeffect is being cycle without stopping. can anybody help me in this here is code:

```react
            import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
            import {Container} from "react-bootstrap";
            import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
            import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
            import TypeBar from "../components/TypeBar";
            import BrandBar from "../components/BrandBar";
            import DeviceList from "../components/DeviceList";
            import {Context} from "../index";
            import {fetchBrands, fetchDevices, fetchTypes} from "../http/deviceAPI";
            import Pages from "../components/Pages";
            import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'; 
            // problem useEffect
This begins here : what is problem is going on it is belong to internet market. this code's main founction is control the limit of products on internet market.
            const Shop = observer(() => {
            const {device} = useContext(Context)
            useEffect(() => {
                fetchTypes().then(data => device.setTypes(data));
                fetchBrands().then(data => device.setBrands(data));
                fetchDevices(null, null, 1, 5).then(data => {
                    device.setDevices(data.rows);
                    device.setTotalCount(data.count);
                })
            }, []) 
            // problem useEffect
            useEffect(() => {
               fetchDevices(device.selectedType.id, device.selectedBrand.id, device.page, 5).then(data => { 
                   device.setDevices(data.rows);
                     device.setTotalCount(data.count);
                 })
             }, [device.page, device.selectedType, device.selectedBrand,]);
             // problem useEffect
```

if it is not correctly what can be put it

Comment: Please take the time to format your question properly with all relevant information and without unnecessary code

Answer (score 0):

Use Effect control is in tag [], if you write

[device.page, device.selectedType, device.selectedBrand,]

it will looping if value of device.page, device.selectedType, device.selectedBrand **change**.

Comment: it didn't work any ideas